# Disable copy paste option in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Need to disable copy and paste event in ckeditor.

Have tried the below method to stop or cancel the paste event, still its not working. What is the mistake here?

CKEditor Version: 4.9.2

```
      CKEDITOR.document.on('paste', function(ev){
        ev.cancel(); //ev.stop();
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function worked for disabling the paste event either by emptying the value or by calling cancel method.

```
     CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
        var editor = ev.editor;
        editor.on('paste', function(even) {
          // even.data.dataValue = '';
            even.cancel();
        });
     });
```